# CSS hide scrollbar bar when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want horizontal overflow and when the screen width is not that wide the DIV starts scrolling right - left, but I want it to look not that ugly I have it right now (scrollbars in the bottom of the div).

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1198px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=content">
    My content here.. 
  </div>
</div>
```

And the other question - is there setting for CSS what allows "swipe" for the div instead of "drag and move".. ?

Comment: set overflow-x:auto to enable scrolling only when there is content overflow

Comment: don't set width in `px` set the width in percentage `width:100%;` it helps your div fit to screen

Comment: @Chris not really what I need, I don't care if it scollable when not that wide.. I just don't like those scroll bar when scroll is in action.

Comment: then you gotta use custom scrollbar, there are many libraries for this you can google for

Comment: Oh you want to be able to scroll but don't show the scrollbar.

Comment: Yes, want to scroll left - right, but don't show the scroll bar.. I think I have seen it somewhere in flat css with libs.. @Chris

Comment: @Evgeny please take a look at this library http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

I believe you can customize it in order to achieve your desire result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a pure CSS solution with browser support you could use the combination of `::-webkit-scrollbar` and some padding like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 17px; /* This hides the right scrollbar */
    padding-bottom: 17px; /* This hides the bottom scrollbar */
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x700" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Better to play around with in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/pavb2hfy/

Comment: Amazing! I think I was looking for this.. What about cross-browser support? I just checked on Chrome, Safari and FF (all OS X), but others .. ?

Comment: Well, you know I just tested with those exact browsers and OS myself also. I don't have the equipment to test on other browsers/OS right now but if you do test them please let me also know of the results. I would imagine this working on most of them. If you want to make sure it's cross-browser I would suggest some plugin.

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN!